# Regex not returning all matches

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I have the following regex (my actual regex is actually a lot more complex but I pinned down my problem to this): `\s(?<number>123|456)\s`

And the following test data:

> " 123 456 "

As expected/wanted result I would have the regex match in 2 matches one with "number" being "123" and the second with number being "456". However, I'm only getting 1 match with "number" being "123".

I did notice that adding another space in between "123" en "456" in the test data does give 2 matches...

Why don't I get the result I want? How to get it right?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @TheSolider There is a PCRE tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern contains consuming `\s` patterns that matches a whitespace before and after a number, and the input contains consecutive numbers separated with a *single* whitespace. If there were two spaces between the numbers, it would work.

Use whitespace boundaries based on lookarounds:

```
(?<!\S)(?<number>123|456)(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yKyrH3/1)

The `(?<!\S)` is a negative lookbehind that will fail the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the *left* of the current location, and `(?!\S)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the *right* of the current location.

`(?<!\S)` is the same as `(?<=^|\s)` and `(?!\S)` is the same as `(?=$|\s)`, but more efficient.

Note that in many situations you might even go with 1 lookahead and use

```
\s(?<number>123|456)(?!\S)
```

It will ensure the consecutive whitespace separated matches are found.